# Is there a method in java that takes an object's attribute as a parameter and returns the object?

Tags: java

I have two classes.

```
public class Person {
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Email;
    public Person(){}
    public Person(int id,String name,String email){
        this.Id=id;
        this.Name=name;
        this.Email=email;
    }
    public int getPersonid(){
        return Id;
    }
    public String getPersonname(){
        return Name;
    }
    public String getPersonemail(){
        return Email;
    }
    public void setPersonid(int id){
        this.Id=id;
    }
    public void setPersonName(String name){
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public void setPersonEmail(String email){
        this.Email=email;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class List_person {
        private ArrayList<Person> Listperson;
        public List_person(){}
        public List_person(ArrayList<Person> listperson){
            this.Listperson=listperson;
        } 
}
```

Is there a method that can take a Person.Id as a parameter and returns the Person that has that Id?
The Id is unique for each person.

Comment: ever thought about using Maps?

Comment: yeah. the get() method in HashMap solves this.thanks